# What is the difference between these declarations in C?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, declaration

In C and C++ what do the following declarations do?

```
const int * i;
int * const i;
const volatile int ip;
const int *i;
```

Are any of the above declarations wrong?

If not what is the meaning and differences between them?

What are the useful uses of above declarations (I mean in which situation we have to use them in C/C++/embedded C)?

Comment: If you're going to edit for grammar and spelling, why not type "If" with an 'I' and not a '!'?

Answer (score 34):

`const int * i;`

`i` is a pointer to constant integer.  `i` can be changed to point to a different value, but the value being pointed to by `i` can not be changed.

`int * const i;`

`i` is a constant pointer to a non-constant integer.  The value pointed to by `i` can be changed, but `i` cannot be changed to point to a different value.

`const volatile int ip;`

This one is kind of tricky.  The fact that `ip` is `const` means that the compiler will not let you change the value of `ip`.  However, it could still be modified in theory, e.g. by taking its address and using the `const_cast` operator.  This is very dangerous and not a good idea, but it is allowed.  The `volatile` qualifier indicates that any time `ip` is accessed, it should always be reloaded from memory, i.e. it should NOT be cached in a register.  This prevents the compiler from making certain optimizations.  You want to use the `volatile` qualifier when you have a variable which might be modified by another thread, or if you're using memory-mapped I/O, or other similar situations which could cause behavior the compiler might not be expecting.  Using `const` and `volatile` on the same variable is rather unusual (but legal) -- you'll usually see one but not the other.

`const int *i;`

This is the same as the first declaration.

Comment: Are you sure that volatile is guaranteed to make a read-only value reflect changes made in another thread? On what implementations? What about multi-core architectures with non-coherent caches?

Comment: If a variable is **declared** `const` (as `ip` is here), then it is undefined behaviour to remove the `const` with `const_cast` in order to modify the value. Also, volatile is not guaranteed to make changes visible to another thread. Particular compilers may make that guarantee.

Comment: Anthony is completely right. volatile does not make your variable thread-aware. also, casting away const from a variable declared const is undefined behaivor.

Comment: volatile guarantees the following AFAIK, stores and reads will not be reordered or optimized away, compiler will not assume that value will not be modified between references to the var

Comment: Just a word from the world of microcontrollers: It's not at all uncommon for a register (for instance, an A/D register) to be a volatile const.  Check out the default header files for HC11 and PIC chips if you have a copy of CodeWarrior lying around.

Comment: `const` and "constant" are two different things. `const` means read-only. A *constant* expression is one that can (and in some cases must) be evaluated at compile time. An example of the difference: `const int r = rand();`

Answer (score 4):

You read variables declarations in C/C++ right-to-left, so to speak.

```
const int *i;  // pointer to a constant int (the integer value doesn't change)

int *const i;  // constant pointer to an int (what i points to doesn't change)

const volatile int ip;  // a constant integer whose value will never be cached by the system
```

They each have their own purposes.  Any C++ textbook or half decent resource will have explanations of each.