# Is the const value parameter in definition but not declaration really C++?

Tags: c++, solaris, language-features

This is similar to (but different from) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters).

Here is some simple test code to illustrate some weirdness I have discovered with Sun CC:

```
//---------------main.cpp
#include "wtc.hpp"

int main(int, char**)
{
  testy t;
  t.lame(99);
  return 0;
}
//--------------wtc.hpp
#ifndef WTC_HPP_INCLUDED
#define WTC_HPP_INCLUDED

class testy
{
public:
  void lame(int );
};

#endif 

//---------------wtc.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "wtc.hpp"

void testy::lame(const int a)
{
  std::cout << "I was passed " << a << "\n";
}

//---------------makefile
#CXX=CC
CXX =g++
#CXXFLAGS= -g 
CXXFLAGS= -g3 -Wall -Werror

OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))

all : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean
clean :
    rm *.o
```

When this was compiled using g++ it compiles, links and does what you would expect when run.
You can also add a ++a; in testy::lame()  and the compiler will complain about changing a read-only variable (as it should).

However when I compile using CC,  I get the following linker error:

```
CC -g   -c -o main.o main.cpp
CC -g   -c -o wtc.o wtc.cpp
CC -g -o all main.o wtc.o
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
void testy::lame(int)               main.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to all
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

checking the object code with nm and C++filt, I find that the g++ version creates a 
testy::lame(int)  symbol,  whereas  CC creates  testy::lame(const int) , hence the linker error.

I looked it up in Stroustrup's book, but can't find this technique mentioned (doesn't mean it's not there!); so is this really a compiler bug, or just a hack that works everywhere else but Solaris?

Comment: Have you sent a bug report to Oracle?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This looks like a compiler problem in `CC`.  The C++ standard says (in 13.1 Overloadable declarations):

> Parameter  declarations  that  differ  only  in  the  presence  or  absence  of const and/or volatile are equivalent.  That  is,  the const and volatile type-specifiers  for  each  parameter  type  are  ignored when determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.

But there are `const`/`volatile` modifiers that can participate in overloading, as the standard mentions shortly afterwards:

> Only the const and volatile type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; const and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type specification  are  significant  and  can  be  used  to  distinguish  overloaded  function  declarations.

Comment: +1, for me that falls into the category of "I understand the logic but that seems like it just contributes to making the language weirder".

Comment: This makes sense where parameters are copied: a `const int` can be copied into an `int`, because they are stored separately. However, a `const int*` can't be copied into an `int*` because the thing that is `const` is shared.

Comment: @JaredPar, a use case here is that it makes no sense to change the API to ensure that your implementation can modify a value parameter.  However, you may wish to put const in your implementation, so that you never accidentally change the function argument (to find bugs like `if (a = 5)`).

Answer (score 4):

The 'const' in the 'const int' parameter should be ignored by the compiler. However, the difference between the declaration and the definition  is bad style, to say the least.

Comment: I really wish that the Standard would at least require a diagnostic message during compilation of the unit containing the mismatch.

Comment: I totally disagree - the constness of the int parameter is an implementation detail that has absolutely no effect on the caller. There's no need to clutter the interface with implementation details.

Comment: +1 to @SCFranch. Absolutely, putting "const" into the declaration just exposes useless implementation details

Comment: @SCFrench "the constness of the int parameter is an implementation detail that has absolutely no effect on the caller" - this is not true. In certain use cases, it can be helpful. For example, large objects are passed in by reference. As a caller, I'd be happy to know the const-ness of the parameters. This can quickly tell third party programmers/users which parameters are inputs and which are inputs & (multiple) outputs at the same time.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297644/is-it-ok-for-function-prototypes-and-function-implementation-signatures-to-use-c for a more detailed description of what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that this is allowed because it makes little difference for the caller. It is not the function that is const, but rather a parameter, and you are making the addition in the definition. Thus, the const you actually added affects only the implementation

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706059/mismatch-between-constructor-definition-and-declaration).

Comment: It does not matter to the caller because you are making a copy of the passed parameter.  If the parameter was passed by reference, it would be different.

Answer (score 0):

I would always match the `const` on both declaration and definition. This would reduce any problems because the signatures would match then.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` is `void func1(const int)` has no affect whatsoever on the function, since the int is passed by value --- a copy of the int is made, and that copy lives only as long as the function call.  Whether or not you change that copy has no bearing on anything.

You are probably confused by the fact that in `void func2(const char*)` the `const` is significant.   But you have to recognized that is different from `void func3(char* const)`.  In the former, it's the character pointed to that cannot change; in the latter, it's the pointer that is (irrelevantly) 'const'

Comment: I'm not confused ;-) My example doesn't have any pointers in it, I wanted to know why this technique worked on one compiler and not the other. Read the question I linked to or try the example yourself. It's a useful technique as it helps to catch errors in the function itself, but *should* make no difference at all for the caller.

Answer (score 0):

See C++ Coding Standards by Alexandrescu #15.  This should work according to him.  The const prevents the implementer of the function from changing the input variable.  IMO the variable should remain const inside the function.  If you need a variable, declare one.  The optimizer will get rid of it for you.

```
int temp = a;
```

Since this does not work here I am advising my class to use the (const int a) in both the prototype and implementation. I am a big fan of using techniques that work for all compilers.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, a const int is not the same as an int.