Is it legal to have a function prototype slightly different from its definition?
//my_struct.h

typedef struct my_struct_t *my_handle;

void f1(my_handle handle);

void f2(my_handle handle);

//my_struct.c
#include "my_struct.h"

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} my_struct_t;

//Is this definition legal?
void f1(my_struct_t *handle)
{
    //bla bla
}

//Is this definition legal?
void f2(const my_struct_t *handle)
{
    //bla bla
}

//main.c
#include "my_struct.h"

void g1(my_handle handle)
{
    //Is this call legal?
    f1(handle);
    
    //Is this call legal?
    f2(handle);
}

In this specific case my_handle is an alias for struct my_struct_t * so I see no reason why the above code should be illegal.
GCC won't let me compile this code, so I guess it's illegal.
What does the ISO c99 standard say about this?
Edit
These are the errors that GCC raises:
https://onlinegdb.com/6hg40rTsV
my_struct.c:11:6: error: conflicting types for ‘f1’; have ‘void(my_struct_t *)’
   11 | void f1(my_struct_t *handle)
      |      ^~
In file included from my_struct.c:1:
my_struct.h:5:6: note: previous declaration of ‘f1’ with type ‘void(struct my_struct_t *)’
    5 | void f1(my_handle handle);
      |      ^~
my_struct.c:17:6: error: conflicting types for ‘f2’; have ‘void(const my_struct_t *)’
   17 | void f2(const my_struct_t *handle)
      |      ^~
In file included from my_struct.c:1:
my_struct.h:7:6: note: previous declaration of ‘f2’ with type ‘void(struct my_struct_t *)’
    7 | void f2(my_handle handle);
      |      ^~


struct my_struct_t is  not defined anywhere in code sample.  Please post its definition.

What do you mean by "alias"? Does your code provide a definition for struct my_struct_t anywhere?

@chux @Gerhardh my_struct_t is defined in my_struct.c file, I'm using an opaque type.

If you get errors, please copy-paste (as text) the build-log into your question showing us the errors. Also when you [edit] your question, add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

I asked about struct my_struct_t, not about my_struct_t. These are 2 different types.

@Gerhardh I didn't know about this difference between struct my_struct_t and my_struct_t, thanks for reporting!

It is one of the reasons of void pointers existance

@0___________ What does that have to do with anything? There's no problem here that can be fixed with void pointers. The problem is that there's 2 different, non-compatible struct types by accident because the OP misunderstood how struct tags work.

See Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?  The short answer is generally "No", though pointer to function types are a plausible exception.

For f2, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297695/3966456

The problem is that

typedef struct my_struct_t *my_handle; and
typedef struct { ... } my_struct_t;

don't refer to the same type.
The first declares a typedef my_handle which is a forward declaration of a pointer to struct my_struct_t a struct with a tag - ok in itself. The second declares a typedef my_struct_t which is a typedef for a different struct with no tag.
At no place in the code do you define struct my_struct_t. Struct tags live in a namespace of their own called the tag namespace, whereas typedef live in the ordinary namespace. (C and C++ are different here.)
The fix is rather trivial, simply add the same tag name as used in the forward declaration to the struct definition:
typedef struct my_struct_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
} my_struct_t;

A much better solution however is to never hide pointers behind typedef, because it only confuses the programmer, thinking they are passing something by value when they aren't.
And even better yet, don't use 2 different names for the same thing because the only thing you achieve with that is also to confuse the programmer. Why do you have something called my_handle in a header called my_struct? That doesn't make sense.
// my_struct.h
typedef struct my_struct_t my_struct_t;

// my_struct.c
struct my_struct_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void f1(my_struct_t* handle);

void f1(my_struct_t* handle)
{
}

And now as it happens, this is the design pattern known as "opaque type" - the way to do private encapsulation in C.

Wow, don't know why I was using my_handle to hide a pointer, now that I see your solution I wonder why I didn't take this path from the beginning, your solution to implement opaque pointers is (IMHO) clearer. Thanks!

f1 isn't okay, and shouldn't even compile. my_struct_t is a typedef name, not a struct name. For the same simplistic reason, f2 isn't okay.
If you changed the struct definition in the source to struct my_struct_t { ... }; and changed the function definitions (not the declarations) to take struct my_struct_t then f1 would compile and work fine, but f2 would still fail to compile, because the definition wouldn't match the declaration.
If you didn't let the source file see the header, then there would likely be no compilation or linking error, but the behavior of the code would be undefined, as there would be a violation of the One Definition Rule between the declarations of f2 (one visible to main.c, the other to my_struct.c).

I changed the definition from the structure to struct my_struct_t { ... } and function definition to void f1(struct my_struct_t *handle){ ... }, and it compiles and runs without any problems, but I wonder is it legal to do such a thing according to the c99 standard? Doesn't this violate the One Definition Rule?

Also changing the definition to typedef struct my_struct_t { ... } my_struct_t; still compiles and runs without problems, again, is it legal according to the c99 standard?

@ParminderSingh There's no problem with a type involving a typedef in one place and the definition of that typedef in another place. A typedef does not declare a new type. It simply adds an alias to refer to a type.

"f1 isn't okay, and shouldn't even compile. my_struct_t is a typedef name, not a struct name"  Eeh? It is a typedef for a struct with no tag and compiles just fine. As it happens this is by far the most common way to define structs in C... That is not the problem here.

Also the "ODR" is C++ jargon. C++ does not have struct tags in the same way as C, which the question is about.

@Lundin Read it again. The typedef says struct my_struct_t. It's okay for there to be a my_struct_t in both the namespace of structs and the namespace of... non-structs (variables, typedefs, etc.) but it's being referred to inconsistently. struct my_struct_t is incomplete.

Ignoring the header, f1 refers to the typedef struct { ... } my_struct_t; which is fine but your answer says otherwise. It should compile just fine but your answer says otherwise. The only problem is that the header function declaration and the .c file function definition refer to different types by accident.

Also it isn't correct that there would be 2 structure and/or functions definitions in violation of C++ jargon - main would only see the forward declaration of an incomplete type and fail to create an instance of that. It may use a pointer to an incomplete type just fine however. And there is only one definition of the function.

I'm referring to the code in the OP's question, not the interpretation of some of it as "by accident" and hence not relevant.

@Sneftel, the question is tagged [c], and Lundin is right about the C semantics of the code presented in it.  In C, struct (and union and enum) tags live in their own namespace, and they are not automatically copied into other namespaces.  On the other hand, typedefed names live in the (one and only) namespace of ordinary identifiers.  There is no issue with the same identifier appearing in both those namespaces, and when one does, that does not automatically create any kind of association.  That is what namespaces are for, after all.

Plainly: "my_struct_t is a typedef name, not a struct name." It is both in the OP's code. A forward declared struct and a separate typedef, both at once.

... and those two are different types, notwithstanding that one is incomplete.

@JohnBollinger That's exactly what I said in an earlier comment.

Well, @Sneftel, I read your "it's being referred to inconsistently" differently.  The point is there is not a single "it", but two different things.  If that's still what you think your answer and comments say, then I guess you can conclude that your prose is not conveying your point effectively.
