# Is there a compiler warning in gcc that will be more particular about mismatches between declaration and definition signatures?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a class that has a member function declaration:

```
void doSomething(int a);
```

and a function definition:

```
void doSomething(int const a) { ... }
```

As covered in [Mismatch between constructor definition and declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706059), these signatures are considered equivalent by a conformant compiler.

What I am hoping to do is find a compiler flag that will warn about this anyway. I am supporting users with a non-conformant compiler that doesn't allow this, and I would like to catch it before they do.

Comment: Err, you want a compiler that warns specifically on _conformant_ code? I understand your reasoning for wanting that in this case, but why would a compiler developer implement anything like that?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the users' non-conformant compiler for this?

Comment: @dragonroot, a good idea, but I would guess that compiler is either expensive as hell or only runs on very special hardware.

Comment: Or is "proprietary". I am in contact with the user to try to come up with a proactive solution, rather than reactive.

Comment: @ildjam, there are many compiler warnings that warn about perfectly conformant code that just isn't *good*.

Comment: Neither `clang -Weverything` nor its static analyzer, `scan-build` warn about this, but `clang` is pretty extensible so you could probably modify it to check for your particular case.

Comment: @us2012 That is the path I was thinking about going down, or just writing a quick ruby script to scan for this specific problem. I build on MSVC as well, so there's still the possibility that it has a warning for this.

Comment: But this warning _wouldn't_ be good – adding `const` to the declaration is just noise (i.e. it doesn't actually change the function signature), and removing it from the definition can impact function-local const-correctness.

Comment: @ildjarn, I fail to see how your point advances answering the question: does the warning exist? I can argue that Microsoft's C4820 is good or bad, but it exists regardless. Also, since I am dealing with a non-conformant compiler that I do not currently have access to, I do not know if adding const to the declaration changes the function signature. When catching possible problems I go by the rule of firsts; the earlier I can detect the problem the better. So I start with compiler warnings, then I try static analysis/scripting, and only then do I fall back on "let me know if it breaks."

Comment: I agree with you in principal, but when supporting users on strange compilers, strange things come up.